# async load both component in react and reducer in redux

Tags: webpack, redux, react-router

l'm going to design a web app that contains several pages. when I click a button, the main content will change but nav bar stay. considering of the size of the app, chunks should be loaded async. the problem is that it's easy to make a async load of react component with react-router and webpack, but not for the state, actions and reducer in redux. is there any way to do so?

Comment: What are you asking here exactly? How to do async with redux? Maybe it's just me but I really can't tell what you are asking for here, maybe add some more details?

Comment: Well. let's say, we have page A and B. so there is a.component.jsx and a.action.js, a.reducer.js and a.initialStore.js, so is B.when i open the main page, there will be a nav bar and A will show in main content by default. if i use `require.ensure` in `getComponent` api in react-router, it's easy to async load B only if i click a link linked to page B. but it can only async load b.component.jsx but not for action, reducer and initialStore. it seems like codes in `configureStore` and `combineReduers` will only run once, so `require.ensure` can't load these only if i need.

Comment: You should ask this more clearly in your question. Right now your question is really quite vauge. Check out SO's resource on asking quesitons - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask